# Which theorem states that a number N can't be perfectly divided by a number greater that N/2 ?

Tags: soft-question

Which theorem states that a number N can't be perfectly divided by a number greater that N/2?

Comment: Why do you need a theorem?  This can be simply proved using properties of inequality.

Comment: The same theorem which says that $N$ can not have a proper divisor $\lt 2$.

Answer (score 6):

Just think about it:

Suppose $M > N/2$. Then $2M > N$.

Thus, $M$ doesn't divide evenly into $N$ Because there is no number $a$ such that $aM = N$.

Answer (score 6):

Proposition: there are no integers $n$ such that
$$ 1 < n < 2 $$

Comment: This gave me a good laugh. Thanks!